# Journalctl show multiple boots working together

Tags: linux, systemd, boot, raspberry-pi, journalctl

While working with my services, and looking for the output using "Journalctl". I found there is miss behavior in my service and two running boots logging and alternate together.

Could some one explain this behavior .

```
journalctl --list-boots
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages.
      Pass -q to turn off this notice.
-2 5c6b3e40d96e4859a68d904493976d01 Sun 2022-09-11 05:40:29 UTC—Mon 2022-09-12 13:29:14 UTC
-1 f92edf9426d244748a5a07e811bdada0 Mon 2022-09-12 18:08:30 UTC—Tue 2022-09-13 18:58:40 UTC
 0 ac0f169caa814d698fc38bde2e702b9d Sun 2022-09-18 11:56:08 UTC—Sun 2022-09-18 14:25:50 UTC
```

```
sudo journalctl -u xxx_serial.service  --since "2022-09-18 07:00:00" --until "2022-09-18 07:01:00"
-- Journal begins at Sat 2022-09-10 21:23:41 UTC, ends at Sun 2022-09-18 14:43:00 UTC. --
Sep 18 07:00:00 DeviceName sudo[722]: post xxx datas
Sep 18 07:00:00 DeviceName sudo[722]: get_xxx_datas
Sep 18 07:00:00 DeviceName sudo[722]: Server 2022-09-18 06:53:34.550670
Sep 18 07:00:00 DeviceName sudo[722]: send_list_url_log_err
Sep 18 07:00:00 DeviceName sudo[722]: 200 b''
-- Boot ac0f169caa814d698fc38bde2e702b9d --
Sep 18 07:00:02 DeviceName systemd[1]: Started My service.
Sep 18 07:00:02 DeviceName sudo[725]:     root : PWD=/home/xxx/deploy ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/script -f -q -a -c sudo /usr/bin/python3 Main.py logs/xxx_serial.log
Sep 18 07:00:02 DeviceName sudo[725]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Sep 18 07:00:02 DeviceName sudo[729]:     root : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/xxx/deploy ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/python3 Main.py
Sep 18 07:00:02 DeviceName sudo[729]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Sep 18 07:00:02 DeviceName sudo[728]: xxx Start: 2022-09-18T07:00:02.777663+00:00
-- Boot 2f9f72851671475095c6d4f3629836d0 --
Sep 18 07:00:03 DeviceName sudo[722]: post xxx datas
Sep 18 07:00:03 DeviceName sudo[722]: get_xxx_datas
Sep 18 07:00:03 DeviceName sudo[722]: Server 2022-09-18 06:53:37.600670
Sep 18 07:00:03 DeviceName sudo[722]: send_list_url_log_err
Sep 18 07:00:03 DeviceName sudo[722]: 200 b''
-- Boot ac0f169caa814d698fc38bde2e702b9d --
Sep 18 07:00:04 DeviceName sudo[728]: read_port
Sep 18 07:00:04 DeviceName sudo[728]: 2.0553 seconds
Sep 18 07:00:04 DeviceName sudo[728]: send set Freq
Sep 18 07:00:04 DeviceName sudo[728]: 5508050d5a019203008016aa
Sep 18 07:00:04 DeviceName sudo[728]: reset_unsend_datalogs
Sep 18 07:00:04 DeviceName sudo[728]: True
Sep 18 07:00:04 DeviceName sudo[728]: post xxx datas
Sep 18 07:00:04 DeviceName sudo[728]: get_xxx_datas
Sep 18 07:00:04 DeviceName sudo[728]: Server 2022-09-18 07:01:24.150670
Sep 18 07:00:04 DeviceName sudo[728]: send_list_url_log_err
Sep 18 07:00:05 DeviceName sudo[728]: send_list_url_log_err HTTPSConnectionPool(host='rnd.spectraqual.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /backend/api/LogWS/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSCo>
-- Boot 2f9f72851671475095c6d4f3629836d0 --
Sep 18 07:00:06 DeviceName sudo[722]: post xxx datas
Sep 18 07:00:06 DeviceName sudo[722]: get_xxx_datas
Sep 18 07:00:06 DeviceName sudo[722]: Server 2022-09-18 06:53:40.550670
Sep 18 07:00:06 DeviceName sudo[722]: send_list_url_log_err
Sep 18 07:00:06 DeviceName sudo[722]: 200 b''
-- Boot ac0f169caa814d698fc38bde2e702b9d --
Sep 18 07:00:07 DeviceName sudo[728]: timeout set xxx
Sep 18 07:00:07 DeviceName sudo[728]: 1663484407.88298 1663484402.232106
Sep 18 07:00:07 DeviceName sudo[728]: 1663484407.88298 1663484407.88298
Sep 18 07:00:07 DeviceName sudo[728]: send set xxx period multiplier
Sep 18 07:00:07 DeviceName sudo[728]: 5509020b5a010001aa
Sep 18 07:00:07 DeviceName sudo[728]: post xxx datas
Sep 18 07:00:07 DeviceName sudo[728]: get_xxx_datas
Sep 18 07:00:07 DeviceName sudo[728]: Server 2022-09-18 07:00:02.482106
Sep 18 07:00:07 DeviceName sudo[728]: send_list_url_log_err
Sep 18 07:00:07 DeviceName sudo[728]: send_list_url_log_err HTTPSConnectionPool(host='rnd.spectraqual.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /backend/api/LogWS/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSCo>
-- Boot 2f9f72851671475095c6d4f3629836d0 --
Sep 18 07:00:09 DeviceName sudo[722]: post xxx datas
Sep 18 07:00:09 DeviceName sudo[722]: get_xxx_datas
Sep 18 07:00:09 DeviceName sudo[722]: Server 2022-09-18 06:53:43.600670
Sep 18 07:00:09 DeviceName sudo[722]: send_list_url_log_err
Sep 18 07:00:09 DeviceName sudo[722]: 200 b''
```